# Xbox controller input not working on unity3d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I can't manage to have my XBox controller work on unity 3d.
Here is the situation:

- I'm on PC with native XBox controller driver and my controller shows in my devices
- When I `Debug.Log(Input.GetJoystickNames().Length);` it shows 1
- Here is my InputManager: [image: Input manager picture]
- Here is my player input managing code :

  ```
  var hAxis = Input.GetAxis("RightJoyHorizontal");
  _walkLeftInput = hAxis > 0;
  _walkRightInput = hAxis < 0;
  _jumpInput = Input.GetButton("AButton");
  ```

Nor the `_jumpInput` or the `hAxis` shows any value (always false and 0) when debugging.

I've tried quitting and restarting unity (for it to catch my controller maybe ?): Same result :(

Any idea on how to fix this ?

Thanks by advance.

Comment: The code is correct, what do you mean exactly by "debugging"? Do you have the focus on the Play window of Unity when pressing the button/moving the stick?

Comment: I mean when I put `Debug.Log()` in my code I see that these variables never change value.
Yes I Do, It works when I set inputs to my keyboard (to LeftKey, RightKey and space)

Comment: ok I just changed usb Port and it worked (I tested the controller on a steam game and saw it was not working) Sorry for the useless question :(